# how to get max no of connection for a particular database

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection

How I can check max no of allowed connection for a particular database in sql server. I am using sql server2008 web edition on my shared hosting server and there is none of way to examine no of allowed connection for a particular database.

I want to sql query to get the result. Can any one tell me what is the best query to make it.
I searched on net with googled and stackoverflow but not get true result.

Thanks

Note: This question may be duplicates but no true result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @@MAX_CONNECTIONS
```

For more information read here [`@@MAX_CONNECTIONS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179874%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

This will show you the number of connections by default. even if you have a different connection setting.

To see the actual number of connections allowed on your instance. Go to your SSMS and

Right Click on Server Name --> Properties --> Connections Tab

[image]

Comment: as per you query 'SELECT @@MAX_CONNECTIONS', It shows all max no of connection for a server instance but I want max no of connection on single database using query. Because on my hosting, there is no wizard to display no of connection for single database.